# How to cach api call on the client

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

How to implement caching api call from react. And make the call again only when the data change on the server (Django rest framework).
I want to make api call ND store the data on local storage on the client side. And only make api call when the data on the server side changed.
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Making the API call to Django REST is the way that React knows if any new data has been added.

If your API call and React front end are implemented correctly, you shouldn't have to keep manually calling the API when the data on the back end changes. React should run the API call each time the page is rendered, so the data will be fresh each time the page is visited. By dynamically displaying the response data from the API call, you will ensure that the data displayed is always up-to-date.

As for the local storage, I would simply update local storage each time the API call is made, checking for what already exists and adding any newly received objects.